# Bibliography style like ieeetr

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, natbib, sorting

Are there any bibliography styles that supports both ordering as in `ieeetr` and author-year (ie. *John et al.*)?

Comment: see package `natbib`

Comment: I have looked at it, I can't find any.

Comment: "John et al." is related to the citation, which is done by `usepackage{natbib}`. A style for the bib maybe `\bibliographystyle{plainnat}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you want autor-year citations plus an "unsorted" (i.e., sorted in order of first citation) bibliography? This is possible with both `natbib` and `biblatex`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{natbib}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
@misc{B02,
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Bravo},
}
@misc{C03,
  author = {Cuthor, C.},
  year = {2003},
  title = {Charlie},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

Some text \citep{B02,A01,C03}.

\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authoryear,sorting=none]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
@misc{B02,
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Bravo},
}
@misc{C03,
  author = {Cuthor, C.},
  year = {2003},
  title = {Charlie},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

Some text \autocite{B02,A01,C03}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

(The filecontents environment is only used to include some external files directly into the example, so that it compiles. It is not necessary for the solution.)